# Find the volume of a cylinder laying on ZX plane

Tags: geometry

I need to find the volume of an object restricted with the $x^{2}+z^{2} < 8$ and $0 < y < 2$ planes. It would be easy if the cylinder were "parallel" to the XY plane, because then:

$$0 < r < 2\sqrt{2}$$
$$0 < \phi < 2\pi$$
$$0 < z < 2$$

But well, how should I handle this here?

Comment: rename your variables, or change the definition of $r,\phi$ !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of this as a cylinder whose base lies in the $x$-$z$ plane, encompassed by the region $x^{2}+z^{2} < r^2 = 8$ and $0 < y < 2$, so that:

$$0 < r  < 2\sqrt{2}$$
$$0 < \phi < 2\pi$$
$$0 < y < 2$$

Comment: Even following the OP's line of thought/approach +1

Comment: @amWhy: I love extended polar coordinates than historical Cartesian ones, so it needs another TU!.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following limits indicating that we are using Cartesian coordinates. I use the symmetric of the solid volume as well.

$$4\int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{8}}\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{8-x^2}}\int_{y=0}^2dydzdx$$

[image]

Comment: Great (+1). You've plotted this shape in MAPLE too ?

Comment: Is it available for free?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Of course not, but you can a preety workable one in Pasje Reza, chahrahe vali asr. It is fun working with it. Great in modeling, Mahdi. Jun mide bara intor kara.

Comment: I was looking for such a software for years! seeing your drawings made me really feel "It is possible to draw such a shapes!". I will purchase it ASAP.

Comment: @BabakS.: Nice graphics again! +1